# Scala: filter and cast in one operation

Tags: scala, collections

Given a heterogeneous sequence, how can I pull out only members of a certain type, and operate on those members in a type-safe way?

If I have:

```
trait Foo
case class Bar(baz: String)
case class Qux(bar: Bar, quux: String) extends Foo
case class Corge(grault: Int) extends Foo
```

If I want to take this sequence of mixed `Corges` and `Quxes`...

```scala
val s = Seq[Foo](Corge(1), Qux(Bar("2"), "3"), Qux(Bar("4"), "5"), Corge(6), Qux(Bar("2"), "7"))
```

...and pull out just the `Quxes`, grouped by `Bar`:

```scala
Map(
  Bar(2) -> List(Qux(Bar(2),3), Qux(Bar(2),7)), 
  Bar(4) -> List(Qux(Bar(4),5))
)
```

I can do this:

```scala
s filter { f => f.isInstanceOf[Qux] } groupBy { 
    f => f.asInstanceOf[Qux].bar }
```

Or I can do this:

```scala
(s.filter({ f => f.isInstanceOf[Qux] }).asInstanceOf[Seq[Qux]]) groupBy { 
    q => q.bar }
```

But either way I need two `instanceOf` checks, when it seems like I should be able to get away with one. Or none. Is there some clever pattern-matching solution I'm missing?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Even better than Daniel Martin's solution is to use `collect`:

```
val a: Seq[Any] = List(1, 2, "asdf", 4)
a: Seq[Any] = List(1, 2, asdf, 4)

val b = a collect { case s: String => s }
b: Seq[String] = List(asdf)
```

Answer (score 1):

No explicit `instanceOf` needed, just the implicit kind you get with using a class in a `case`:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> val a : Seq[Any] = List(1, 2, "asdf", 4)
a: Seq[Any] = List(1, 2, asdf, 4)

scala> val b = a flatMap {i:Any => i match { case s:String => Some(s); case _ => None }}
b: Seq[String] = List(asdf)
```

Note the types of `a` and `b`.